# How use count for value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

How to use count joining with different tables. Please have a look at my queries. Here i am using CROSS APPLY. But i am not getting the actual result.
how i can to get all the item from item table not in incident table.

Tabel : Inc_cat

```
+------------+--------------+--+
| inc_cat_id |  inc_cat_n   |  |
+------------+--------------+--+
|          1 | Support      |  |
|          2 | PM           |  |
|          3 | Installation |  |
+------------+--------------+--+
```

Table:incident

```
+-------------+---------+------------+-----------------+
| incident_id | item_id | inc_cat_id | date_logged     |
+-------------+---------+------------+-----------------+
|         100 |     555 |          1 |  2016-01-01     |
|         101 |     555 |          2 |  2016-01-18     |
|         103 |     444 |          3 |  2016-02-10     |
|         104 |     444 |          2 |  2016-04-01     |
|         105 |     666 |          1 |  2016-04-09     |
|         106 |     555 |          2 |  2016-04-20     |
+-------------+---------+------------+-----------------+
```

Table:item

```
+---------+---------+--+
| item_id | cust_id |  |
+---------+---------+--+
|     444 |      34 |  |
|     555 |      34 |  |
|     666 |      76 |  |
|     333 |      34 |  |
|     222 |      34 |  |
|     111 |      34 |  |
+---------+---------+--+
```

Result:

```
+---------+----------------+-----------+---------------------+
| item_id | count(Support) | count(PM) | count(Installation) |
+---------+----------------+-----------+---------------------+
|     555 |              0 |         1 |                   0 |
|     444 |              0 |         1 |                   0 |
|     666 |              0 |         0 |                   0 |
|     333 |              0 |         0 |                   0 |
|     222 |              0 |         0 |                   0 |
|     111 |              0 |         0 |                   0 |
+---------+----------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

My Query:

```
 SELECT i.item_ID, 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN i.inc_cat_id = ic.inc_cat_id AND i.inc_cat_id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS cntSupport,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN i.inc_cat_id = ic.inc_cat_id AND i.inc_cat_id = 2 THEN 1 END) AS cntPM,
 COUNT(CASE WHEN i.inc_cat_id = ic.inc_cat_id AND i.inc_cat_id = 3 THEN 1 END) AS cntInstallation
 FROM @incident i
 CROSS APPLY @incCat ic
 WHERE (i.date_logged BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-04-30')AND i.cust_id='34'
 GROUP BY i.item_ID
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a `CROSS APPLY`. A simple `LEFT JOIN` will do:

```
SELECT i.item_id,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN inc.inc_cat_id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS cntSupport,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN inc.inc_cat_id = 2 THEN 1 END) AS cntPM,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN inc.inc_cat_id = 3 THEN 1 END) AS cntInstallation
FROM Item AS i
LEFT JOIN Incident AS inc ON i.item_id = inc.item_id AND
                      inc.date_logged BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-04-30'        
WHERE i.cust_id = 34
GROUP BY i.item_id
```

You just need to start by table `Item`, so as to get *all* items returned, as in the expected result set in the OP.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08bc1/1)

Comment: That's a better answer then mine, if the OP also needs to show `0` count for items not in the `Incident` table, however the query in the question suggests otherwise...

Comment: @Giorgos : All counts getting 0

Comment: @Salman I'm not able to reproduce the issue. Please check the edit I made (fiddle demo).

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos thanks for answer, if i am using where condition to incident. how can i use it

Comment: @Salman You have to add it between the `LEFT JOIN` and the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos i have modified my Query and Result table. Please have a look into that, Shall we need to do any modification on your answer .. Thanks

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos thanks much , if i add filter by cust_id it will skip the remaining item from item? ie, cust_id='34'

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Please look into my result and filter now

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, your query is over complicated:

```
SELECT item_ID, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN .inc_cat_id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS cntSupport,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN inc_cat_id = 2 THEN 1 END) AS cntPM,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN inc_cat_id = 3 THEN 1 END) AS cntInstallation
  FROM @incident 
 GROUP BY item_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

With the addition of `logged_date` column, you just need to add it in the `ON` clause. You need to use `sp_executesql` instead of `EXEC` now to prevent sql injection:

```
DECLARE @fromDate DATE = '2016-04-01',
        @toDate DATE = '2016-04-30';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql =
'SELECT
    i.item_id' + CHAR(10) +
(SELECT
'   , COUNT(CASE WHEN inc.inc_cat_id = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), inc_cat_id) + 
' THEN 1 END) AS ' + QUOTENAME('count(' + inc_cat_n + ')') + CHAR(10)
FROM #Inc_cat
ORDER BY inc_cat_id
FOR XML PATH('')
) +
'FROM #item AS i
LEFT JOIN #incident AS inc
    ON i.item_id = inc.item_id
    AND inc.date_logged BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate
GROUP BY i.item_id;';

PRINT (@sql);
EXEC sp_executesql
        @sql,
        N'@fromDate DATE, @toDate DATE',
        @fromDate,
        @toDate
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/490881)</kbd>

---

Giorgos answer is good if you only have that 3 `Inc_cat`s. However, if you have unknown number of `Inc_cat`s, you need to do it dynamically. Here is a method using a [dynamic crosstab](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql =
'SELECT
    i.item_id' + CHAR(10) +
(SELECT
'   , COUNT(CASE WHEN inc.inc_cat_id = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), inc_cat_id) + 
' THEN 1 END) AS ' + QUOTENAME('count(' + inc_cat_n + ')') + CHAR(10)
FROM Inc_cat
ORDER BY inc_cat_id
FOR XML PATH('')
) +
'FROM Item AS i
LEFT JOIN Incident AS inc
    ON i.item_id = inc.item_id
GROUP BY i.item_id;';

PRINT (@sql);
EXEC (@sql);
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/490872)</kbd>

Basically, it's just a dynamic version of Giorgos' answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have did some small changes my query and table. Please look into that .. Thanks

Comment: i have added one more filter in my query , lets see the result now